# How to sort a HashMap by Key and then Value using Comparator (pasting all code, post will be long)

Tags: java

Starting from scratch so that peoples eyes don't bleed, here is my most recent progress:

```
        Set<Entry<GregorianCalendar, Event>> map = (MyCalendarTester.myCal.getMyCalHash().entrySet());

        LinkedList<Map.Entry<GregorianCalendar, Event>> list = new LinkedList<Map.Entry<GregorianCalendar,Event>>(map); 
          Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Map.Entry<GregorianCalendar, Event>>() {
                public int compare(Map.Entry<GregorianCalendar, Event> e1, Map.Entry<GregorianCalendar,Event> e2) {
                    int r;
                    r = e1.getKey().compareTo(e2.getKey());
                    if (r!=0) return r;
                    r = e1.getValue().compareTo(e2.getValue());
                    return r;
                }
            });

          Iterator<Map.Entry<GregorianCalendar,Event>> i2 = list.iterator();
            while (i2.hasNext()) {

                System.out.println(i2.next() + " , ");
            }
```

And here is how my compareTo works:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Object e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   int hour = ((Event) e).getStartTime().get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
   int minute = ((Event) e).getStartTime().get(Calendar.MINUTE);
   int anotherHour = this.startTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
   int anotherMinute = this.startTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

   if(anotherHour - hour == 0 ){
       return anotherMinute - minute;
   }else{
       return anotherHour - hour;
   }



}
```

By creating the following days and events:
Test4
04/16/2016
2:23,5:56

Test5
03/15/2015
1:11

Test6
08/29/2017
7:51,23:59

Test7
04/16/2016
1:23,5:56

My program produces:

java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=?,areFieldsSet=false,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="America/Los_Angeles",offset=-28800000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,transitions=185,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=America/Los_Angeles,offset=-28800000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=3,startMonth=2,startDay=8,startDayOfWeek=1,startTime=7200000,startTimeMode=0,endMode=3,endMonth=10,endDay=1,endDayOfWeek=1,endTime=7200000,endTimeMode=0]],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2015,MONTH=3,WEEK_OF_YEAR=12,WEEK_OF_MONTH=3,DAY_OF_MONTH=15,DAY_OF_YEAR=75,DAY_OF_WEEK=2,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=3,AM_PM=0,HOUR=9,HOUR_OF_DAY=9,MINUTE=30,SECOND=38,MILLISECOND=260,ZONE_OFFSET=-28800000,DST_OFFSET=3600000]=Event@791d9ad , 
java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=?,areFieldsSet=false,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="America/Los_Angeles",offset=-28800000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,transitions=185,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=America/Los_Angeles,offset=-28800000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=3,startMonth=2,startDay=8,startDayOfWeek=1,startTime=7200000,startTimeMode=0,endMode=3,endMonth=10,endDay=1,endDayOfWeek=1,endTime=7200000,endTimeMode=0]],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2016,MONTH=4,WEEK_OF_YEAR=12,WEEK_OF_MONTH=3,DAY_OF_MONTH=16,DAY_OF_YEAR=75,DAY_OF_WEEK=2,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=3,AM_PM=0,HOUR=9,HOUR_OF_DAY=9,MINUTE=30,SECOND=38,MILLISECOND=260,ZONE_OFFSET=-28800000,DST_OFFSET=3600000]=Event@7869f0bc , 
java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=?,areFieldsSet=false,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="America/Los_Angeles",offset=-28800000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,transitions=185,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=America/Los_Angeles,offset=-28800000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=3,startMonth=2,startDay=8,startDayOfWeek=1,startTime=7200000,startTimeMode=0,endMode=3,endMonth=10,endDay=1,endDayOfWeek=1,endTime=7200000,endTimeMode=0]],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2017,MONTH=8,WEEK_OF_YEAR=12,WEEK_OF_MONTH=3,DAY_OF_MONTH=29,DAY_OF_YEAR=75,DAY_OF_WEEK=2,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=3,AM_PM=0,HOUR=9,HOUR_OF_DAY=9,MINUTE=30,SECOND=38,MILLISECOND=462,ZONE_OFFSET=-28800000,DST_OFFSET=3600000]=Event@733c0466 ,

(sorry, not sure how to nicely format that one)
The issue is that (1) they are all identical except for the DAY_OF_MONTH, (2) it eats up the duplicate day, and then (3) I'm not sure how to get pull out the relevant information that I need out of the Calendar using the LinkedList (basically how to format it).

Again, sorry this is taking so long, but this is just beyond my programming capabilities to figure out on my own.

Comment: HashMaps cannot be sorted, full stop. You could copy the keys and/or values into a List, then sort that?

Comment: Also, nobody (including me) wants to look through all your code. (Which is why I haven't done that, and my comment is about the question in the title)

Comment: @immibis I know, but whenever I tried to zone in on a particular portion, I haven't received good enough answers that could work with my setup. Anyway, I edited in the most relevant portion. (which is also my latest attempt)

Comment: There's another thing... a map, by definition, only contains one value for each key. Therefore you will *never* find two keys that match in the same map.

Comment: But one key can have multiple values, correct? So then I need to sort the multiple values.

Comment: No. For any given key, either it maps to exactly one value, or it's not in the map.

Comment: Like @immibis said, please trim your code to the relevant portions that are not working.  In this case, try to create a small example with a hashmap, and if that doesn't work, then post your questions here.

Comment: @immibis I don't understand. My HashMap seems to contain multiple keys (some are the same) and different values. It works in all other aspects of the program, I just can't get that extra dimension of sorting to work.

Comment: I thought I provided a suggestion in an answer to be able to sort this type of issue yesterday, did you post this again. I did not hear if you tried my suggestion.  Your compareTo method in your Event class is too complex, the method I provided yesterday makes it much easy

Comment: @faljbour I'm trying to sort by startTime, not endTime. But that can easily be swapped on my end. The problem is that I'm not sure what you are doing with the milliseconds. But specifically, there is no way for me to get the field key.get(DAY_OF_MONTH.SECOND). Even if I do key.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH.SECOND), the compiler doesn't know what that is. I'm not ignoring your answer, I just wasn't able to implement it with what I have.

Comment: there is a typo, remove the .SECOND at the end of the DAY_OF_MONTH.  what I understood from yesterday's post that the keys in the hashmap are GreeorianCalendar which hold only the date but not time and the values are Event objects defined by a class you defined which hold the time field which is also a Calendar.  what I showed is you can combine the loop through all of the hashmap, get every event object, add the year, month, day to the time field in Event, then sort them based on the compareTo method I provided.

Comment: To compare two Calendar objects, it is best to get the seconds value of the first object and compare with seconds object of the second object instead of comparing, year, month, day, hours .....  I can type the solution again with more description if you like

Comment: to be clear getTimeInMillis as suggested or you can use getTime which returns the seconds are the milliseconds or seconds since Jan1, 1970.

Comment: You should strive to keep your posts simple and to-the-point.  The question being asked is about hash maps.  The fact that you have reams of code to go along with it does not add much value to the question.

Comment: You can try using a Guava [`TreeMultimap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/TreeMultimap.html) which will allow you to do two things: (1) have multiple values for each key and (2) keep the keys __and__ the values sorted (according to natural order or provided comparator).

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as `GregorianCalendar` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 & Java 9. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 0):

Use a `TreeMap` instead, it is sorted by key. You can't have the best of both worlds at the same time (O(1) access time and sorted keys). There are obviously ways to iterate in a sorted manner but those rely on copying all keys to a list, sorting that list, and then getting all values in that order. But really, if you want a map that is sorted by key, you should use a TreeMap. It's made *specifically* for that purpose.

Comment: I have used a TreeSet which worked nicely for sorting the keys, but now I need a second level of sorting depth to sort the values that fall on the same dates (keys).

Comment: `TreeSet` is a sorted `Set`, which is a collection of single values. `TreeMap`, with a **MAP** at the end, is a sorted `Map`, which is a collection of key-value pairs. You could use a `TreeMap<Object, TreeSet<Object>>` to have a structure that is *always* sorted by key, and the values for the same key are also always sorted.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a Guava [`TreeMultimap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/TreeMultimap.html) which will allow you to do two things: (1) have multiple values for each key and (2) keep the keys and the values sorted (according to natural order or provided comparator):

```
// For natural ordering of both K and V:
TreeMultimap<K, V> mMap = TreeMultimap.create();

// For custom ordering of K and V:
TreeMultimap<K, V> mMap = TreeMultimap.create(
  new Comparator<K>() {
    int compare(K o1, K o2) {
      // your implementation here
    }
  },
  new Comparator<V>() {
    int compare(V o1, V o2) {
      // your implementation here
    }
  }
);
```

Next, you can iterate the multimap K,V pairs like this:

```
for (Map.Entry<K, V> e : mMap.entries()) {
  // entries are sorted by K first and then by V
  K k = e.getKey();
  V v = e.getValue();
  // do something with k, v
}
```

More information about `MultiMap` is available [here](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Multimap).

Comment: Interesting, I've never heard of a Guava TreeMultimap. I'll look into it and see if it helps. Thank you.

Comment: If you're not familiar with Guava at all, check it out, it's a life saver.